# AutoTransition not working in Motion layout

Tags: android, android-motionlayout

I currently learning motionlayout. I created a small app in which the image in the center rotates for 5 seconds. onClick and onSwipe attributes are working fine on the device but with autotransition = animateToEnd nothing is happening when I run the app on the device. Basically I want my transition to happen automatically as the activity starts.
Here is my motion layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/activity_main_scene">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:contentDescription="TODO"
        android:src="@drawable/background" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/moon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_moon"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Here is my motionScene:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:motion="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        motion:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end"
        motion:constraintSetStart="@id/start"
        motion:duration="5000"
        motion:autoTransition="animateToEnd">
       <KeyFrameSet>
           <KeyCycle
               motion:motionTarget="@+id/moon"
               motion:framePosition="0"
               motion:wavePeriod="2"
               motion:waveShape="sawtooth"
               android:rotation="180"
               motion:waveOffset="0" />
       </KeyFrameSet>
    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start">
    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/end">
    </ConstraintSet>
</MotionScene>
```

If there is any alternative way to run transition with motion layout please do tell.
**For running the app I used to create debug apk and then run it on my device.

Comment: don't use 2.0.0-beta7. Use 2.0.0-beta4. It is working fine.

Answer (score 7):

just add

```
app:motionInterpolator="linear"
```

to the Transition tag

Comment: It worked for me. But can you please explain why it is working?

Answer (score 3):

note: when the version of Constrainlayout is 2.0.0-beta6 and higher, I find some differ in MotionLayout. there is the condition that this.mCurrentTransition == transition in MotionScene#autoTransition(...). I suspect the condition filter the operation back to start.

there are two solutions.
1.Downgrade to 2.0.0-beta6 or lower.
2. control it programmatically:

```
motionLayout.setTransitionListener(object : TransitionAdapter() {
    override fun onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout: MotionLayout, currentId: Int) {
        super.onTransitionCompleted(motionLayout, currentId)
        if (currentId == R.id.end) {
            motionLayout.transitionToStart()
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: the best way is for Google developer to solve it and support  `autoTransition`

Comment: for me only this solution works, but I changed transitionToStart to transitionToEnd... but still dont know why this works but autoTransition doesn't...

Answer (score 1):

Did you use constraintLayout:**2.0.0-beta7**? I think that version has a bug. Downgrade to **2.0.0-beta6** should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

It is because of its version. Use androidx.constraintlayout.constraintlayout-2.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Auto transition wont work if you dont set your objects like imageview in  constraint set add any widget you want to transtion inside constraint set  use constraint tag and it will work
On start constraint set put first postion of your image
On end  constraint set put postion of your image view when after 5 sec done in your case use android:rotation=""

Comment: I already did that but still it doesn't work. Also  [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uJKVcEqOAV8&t=1084s) here, the person didn't mentioned any widget inside constraint tag but still the animation works fine with auto transition. Also I tried setting transitionListener and toasting up messages with transition change what I found is transition gets started but nothing moves on the mobile screen.

Comment: @IshanTrivedi  use easyinout method on sens xml file if doesn't work agian try test with onclick or onswipe to see its work at all !

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the KeyCycle at motion:framePosition="0" it's a known issue.

KeyCycle really needs 2 or 3 values to be meaning full 
Typically position 0 and position 100 and one in the middle. 
If you only put one in it will replicate a start(0) and end(100).

The value of KeyCycles in this case is that you can vary the speed of the rotation over time. So that you can ramp up the speed or start it fast and slow down over time.